# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - Javascript

Tags: javascript, import, export

i am facing a problem with imports in js for about 6 days now. I just can't solve that problem. I have a simple flask app written in python and a little bit of js code running on the client. I have two js files and i want to import a variable from the first in the second script. I don't know whats the problem, i tried it with several combinations but it just wont run.

first.js:

```
// Local Config
let ADD_SONG_URL = "TEST";
export {ADD_SONG_URL};
```

second.js:

```
import {ADD_SONG_URL} from "./first.js";
console.log(ADD_SONG_URL);
```

file.html:

```
<script type="module" src="/static/js/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/second.js"></script>
```

In Intellij everything looks fine, but in the browser i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I am relatively new to frontend programming so i'm desperate because i can't fix this problem. I hope anyone have a quick answer and thats not a big thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your script type from `text/javascript` to `module`. I think it should work.

```
<script type="module" src="/static/js/first.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/static/js/second.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay wow! :D thats just working. Could you explain why its so important that both are type=module? i thought the main script should still have the text/javascript type cause literally it is the script.

Comment: Your script type have to be `module` if you are using import and export in them. You can have a look https://javascript.info/modules-intro